# Unique id for two tables in different database on same server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables in two different databases on the same server (MS SQL-Server 2012). I want an id of the datatype int that is unique for both tables. I have tried using a sequence but it seems it is not allowed over different databases. What else can I try? From time to time I need to update fields in both directions.

Comment: The aptly named `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: In truth, if these tables are in 2 different databases though, then why does the reuse matter? If the data is related, they should really be in the same database; then you *can* use things like a `SEQUENCE` accordingly.

Comment: Larnu, as I understand it uniqueidentifier is not int. I edited my question to make clear that I nee that.

Comment: make one use positive and the other negative numbers perhaps? but really `uniqueidentifier` is the _right_ solution here not ints

Comment: You are of course right Larnu that they should be in the same database but now they are not and it is not much I can do about that.

Comment: Then, like I mentioned, you should really have the objects in the same data ase. If they are in separate ones they are by definition not related so the values being the same don't matter. What @Jamiec suggests is a work around though; at the end of the day an `IDENTITY`/`SEQUENCE` is an arbitrary number, so one being positive and the other negative would result in no reuse. Just make sure that *if* the value is to be the clustered index the one using the negative numbers is indexed descending, *not* ascending.

Comment: Is there an expectation that you'd use the same ID in both databases for any purpose? Say that the ID 123 got generated (via whatever mechanism). Would all references to it solely be in one database or the other?

Comment: @Charlieface that doesn't work, you'll get the error `Object 'dbo.Sequence' is not a sequence object.` when you try to use `NEXT VALUE FOR` on it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this in 2 separate databases is to define a partitioning strategy yourself, such as

- DatabaseA useses positive integers, while DatabaseB uses negative integers (ensure your indexing strategy is aware)
- DatabaseA useses the range 0 < key < 1000000, Database B useses the range key>1000000 (Ensure that DatabaseA will never have more than a million rows)

I'll re-iterate my comment though, this is basically what `uniqueidentifier` is for - having a unique key which is not duplicated with any degree of likelyhood across separate platforms

Answer (score 0):

Change your desired range here

```
declare @UniqueValue int=0

while (@UniqueValue=0)
begin 
select @UniqueValue=T.FoundValue from 
(
SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(2147483647)-2147483647) FoundValue
)T
where T.FoundValue not in (
select * from 
(select ID from DB1.Table
Union  all
select ID from DB2.Table
)A)
end

select @UniqueValue
```